# How to add a value to a tableView?

Tags: java, javafx-8

[image]

I will calculate the total price value  in the code based on which radioButton will be selected and I will display it into the "Here will be the price" label. I don't know how to add the price value in the TableView after it will be calculated. The TableView is bound to a database, so the value must also be added in the database, after the  Rent Button will be pressed.

Comment: So you don't know how to add the vlaue into the dabatase ?

Comment: I don't know how to add the price value in the tableView and in the database